# How to find the corresponding pair of inbound and outbound messages in a soap handler

Tags: soap, handler

When I use a SOAP handler, I get the handleMessage method invoked both on the inbound and the outbound messasge. However, if there are many clients sending many messages, how can I see which two calls to handleMessage belong to a pair of corresponding inbound and outbound message? E.g. I want to build a SOAP handler which measures performance by determining the system time on the way in and on the way out, so I have to catch a pair of corresponding messages.
Thanks for your help,
Thomas

Comment: It would help to add details about the web service framework or library you are using, maybe show some code if possible, otherwise we can't know what kind of handler you have in place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer:

What I had in mind was something like

```
public class ServerMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

private long timeIn;

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
    boolean outbound = (Boolean) messageContext.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (!outbound) {this.timeIn = System.currentTimeMillis();}
    else {System.out.println("time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.timeIn));}
    return true;
}
...
}
```

So in order to measure the processing time, it is important to compare the outgoing time with the corresponding entering time, not just the entering time for some other client that entered in the meantime.
But a solution would be to use e.g. messageContext.get (MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST):

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
    boolean outbound = (Boolean) messageContext.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest) messageContext.get (MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    if (!outbound) {
        request.setAttribute("timeIn", System.currentTimeMillis());
    } else {
        Long timeIn = (Long) request.getAttribute("timeIn");
        System.out.println("time needed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeIn));
    }
    return true;
}
```